# Log each line of an exception separately

Tags: python, logging, syslog

I'm logging to syslog (on its way to papertrail), and I'd like to have exceptions visible in the final logs.

Using a vanilla configuration, exceptions look like this:

```
Sep 02 08:35:16 web1.stage.releng.webapp.scl3.mozilla.com relengapi: ﻿Exception on /tokenauth/tokens [POST]#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/data/www/relengapi/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request#012    rv = self.dispatch_request()#012  File "/data/www/relengapi/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request#012    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)#012
```

which is to say, a very long line delimited by #012.  In fact, papertrail cuts it off before it finishes.

I'd like to find a way to split that exception out into multiple lines.  I'm willing to monkeypatch or subclass logging modules to do so, but I can't find a good place.

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be working:

```
old_log = logging.Logger._log
def new_log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None):
    old_log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=extra)
    if exc_info:
        if not isinstance(exc_info, tuple):
            exc_info = sys.exc_info()
        exc_text = logging._defaultFormatter.formatException(exc_info)
        for line in exc_text.split("\n"):
            old_log(self, level, line, ())
logging.Logger._log = new_log
```

but I dislike the use of `logging._defaultFormatter`.  Is there a better way?